# Transitions between Screens in MOqui

Tags: moqui

I have been looking for transitions between screens but was unable to find the best practice to navigate through screens .Making sub screens and entry in apps.xml was a try but it gives a  link on the top of the page which is not what I want . I want make transitions as we make in html-5 or earlier versions through anchor tag. What is the best practice to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Below code in a screen can generate the code you want. But you would need to override the "label" macro by yourself to let it contain a "link" that is simply done by add a <#recurse/> in macro "label".

```
<transition name="gotoScreen1">
    <default-response url="Screen1"/>
</transition>

<widget>
   <label type="pre">
       <link url="gotoScreen1" link-type="anchor" text="This test link from FTL"/>
   <label type="pre">
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

A screen transition is a part of a screen definition that specifies how to process input to the transition (if there are logic/actions associated with it) and which screen to transition to when it is complete.

To access a screen transition you just have the browser (or client) go to the URL of the screen, plus the name of the transition separated by a forward slash (i.e. in the URL treat the transition as a directory or file within the "directory" of the screen). This can be done with a hyperlink, a form target, an AJAX call, etc.

To create a link or button using the XML Screen (or XML Form) in Moqui, just use the "link" tag.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance ,it was a useful help for me . I was able to navigate through screens  by writing the below code....                                        <pre><a href="${sri.makeUrlByType("Screen1", "transition", null, "false").getUrl()}">This test link from FTL</a></pre>               and writing the transition tag and default response attribute a got my work done . But Still I am looking for better ways which makes the coding a bit more easy.